# Триггер в SQLite

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Написал триггер для добавления даты если поле равно null вот код

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON products 
BEGIN 
SELECT CASE 
WHEN (NEW.added_date ISNULL) 
THEN NEW.added_date = DATE('now')  
END;
END;
```

он ничего не меняет. Помогите пожалуйста, уже не знаю что делать

Comment: Зачем тут CASE? просто `SET NEW.added_date = COALESCE(NEW.added_date, DATE('now'))`. А ничего не меняет именно по причине отсутствия `SET`, вероятно...

Comment: А ещё лучше - не возиться с триггерами, а просто указать для этого поля в структуре таблицы `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` - и оно само...

Comment: @Akina ввел `CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON products 
BEGIN 
SET NEW.added_date = COALESCE(NEW.added_date, DATE('now')) 
END;`
Выводит syntax error там где SET, если не надоедаю, то может знаете в чем дело?